# how to embed oracle XE database in executable jar?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing, jdbc

I have developed java application using java swings and oracle XE database in "myecplise". I have also created executable jar file and it runs fine in my pc but it is showing jdbc.odbc ClassNotFound exception and NullPointer Exception in other pc

my connection code is

```
    import java.sql.*;

    public class Connect {

    static Connection con=null;

        public static Connection ConnectDB(){

        try{

           // Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

             DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost"); 

             return con;



        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

    }      
}
}
```

Comment: You should never call `DriverManager.registerDriver` yourself (very rare exceptions aside). That is done by the driver itself when it gets loaded (either automatically if it is JDBC 4.0), or through `Class.forName`).

Answer (score 0):

The `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:system/system@localhost")` states that the driver manager will connect to the database located at your **localhost**. On the other PC it tries to locate the database on that other machine, since the database is not present there the exception will occur.

You have to change the connection to something like:

```
    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@arg0:arg1:arg2", arg3, arg4);
```

Where

arg0: the IP of the machine that hosts the database.

arg1: The port that the database is listening to.

arg2: the SID of the database.

arg3: the schema username.

arg4: the schema password.

Comment: thanks for reply,

     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","system"); 

like this, right??

I tried that too but still its not working...

Comment: The problem is that there is no database on the second machine -at leat not with the same schema or SID-, the database is located on the first machine. You have add the IP of the original machine that contains the database instead of the "localhost".